# Convert String to List in Python Without Using Eval?

Tags: python, string, list, eval

I have a string, something like this: `"[['Cheese', 72], ['Milk', 45], ['Bread', 22]]"`.

I want to convert this to a list. I know I can use eval(string) to get the list, but eval scares me because of its potential for catastrophe (and because I can get a non-list as valid output). Is there another saner/safer way to turn this string into a list? I know it's a list and anything that isn't a list is invalid data (and should be checked for and/or throw an error).

Comment: You will want to check out this module: http://docs.python.org/2/library/ast.html

Comment: As a bit of background: I inherited a Django app where the previous developer stored a list of items in a database table as a string. It doesn't *have* to be done that way, and I'm not against using a data migration to convert to JSON, but if there's a "secret handshake" to parse a list, fine by me.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you insist on doing it this way, you can use the ast.literal_eval function.

```
>>> import ast
>>> foo = "[['Cheese', 72], ['Milk', 45], ['Bread', 22]]"
>>> ast.literal_eval(foo)
[['Cheese', 72], ['Milk', 45], ['Bread', 22]]
```

I'm sure others will tell you that you're likely doing something wrong, or to use a library like JSON to transport arbitrary data structures like this one, and I wouldn't disagree.

Comment: Just in case someone get ValueError, remember to change foo first to string and  then apply ast.literal_eval(foo)

Answer (score 4):

Try to use the [`json` module](http://docs.python.org/2/library/json.html):

```
import json
s = "[['Cheese', 72], ['Milk', 45], ['Bread', 22]]"
s = s.replace("'", '"')
print json.loads(s)
```

Answer (score 1):

You might consider using the `json` module to deserialize and making sure your strings are in [json format](http://json.org/).

See http://docs.python.org/2/library/json.html for details about using this module.

Answer (score 0):

Here's one way:
exec("list = "+foo)
This should make a variable 'list' with the list in string converted to a real list.
This also works for dictionaries, arrays, bools, etc in strings.

Comment: I'm not a Python expert. Is this really any better than using `eval`? Isn't it still just as exploitable?